# REACT - auto submit form after files uploaded to state the contains array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I want to submit a form that send a request to server automatically.

This is how I load the files into the state -

```
  const onUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const id = event.target.id;
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const file = event.target.files![0];

    fileReader.onload = () => {
      setCSVFilesState([...CSVFilesState, { id, file: fileReader.result }]);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
```

I'm uploading 2 files to the `CSVFilesState` both in the form.

I want to fire the request when both files are in the state. How can I wait for the files and only then send the request?

This is my onSubmit function -

```
  const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    backendAPIAxios
      .post("/", CSVFilesState)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<IServerResponseData>) => {

      })
      .catch((e: AxiosError) => {

      });
  };
```

Tried to do that (didn't work) -

```
     const onUpload = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const id = event.target.id;
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        const file = event.target.files![0];
    
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          setCSVFilesState([...CSVFilesState, { id, file: fileReader.result }]);
        };
    
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

   if (CSVFilesState.length === 1) onSubmit(event);
      };
```

Comment: you can check for length of the data. If count equals 2 then and then only you can make an API call. This would solve the issue in your case. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @KrunalShah where should I put it in the code? when I tried to do it, with CSV.length === 1 (array starts from 0). It doesn't wait for the file

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    if(CSVFilesState.length === 2){
        onSubmit()
    }
},[CSVFilesState])
```

Checked the count of CSVFilesState.

Comment: added code to question

Comment: length has nothing to do with indexing of array.
As you want to check 2 files so condition should be like CSVFilesState.length===2 not CSVFilesState.length===1

Comment: @devedvdevdev try the code i provided and also console the state before if clause